# Bizarre issue I'm having with my jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, recursion, accessibility, tabindex

This is an accessibility bug I've been assigned at work where items aren't traverse-able within a dialog box using tab.

Really strange issue, hoping you guys can help.

We begin with the following code... this is wrapped in some object variables something like

```
(<selector>).dialog(bam.ui.dialogOptions());
```

In dialogOptions I put a comment so you can see where I call my function .tabAccess; This is an attempt of mine to utilize tabindex within my dialog and FORCE it to do what I want within the dialog.

```
dialogOptions: function (options) {
        var settings = { title: "", showScrollbar: true };
        if (options) {
            $.extend(settings, options);
        }
        return {
            height: 373,
            width: 648,
            modal: true,
            title: settings.title,
            resizable: false,
            open: function (event, ui) {
                $(this).parent().focus();
                $('html').addClass("hidden-scrollbar");
                $(event.target).html(DialogLoadingdlg);
                $(this).find("input:enabled:last").live("blur", function () { $("a.ui-dialog-titlebar-close").focus(); });
                $("span.ui-icon-closethick").html(closeImage);
/*TAB ACCESS CALLED HERE; 
ASSIGNING IT TO THE PARENT ELEMENT OF THE DIALOG CONTENT, 
THAT BEING THE DIALOG ITSELF*/
                $(this).parent().tabAccess(); 
            },
            close: function (event, ui) {
                $('.operate a').removeClass("selected");
                if (settings.showScrollbar)
                    $('html').removeClass("hidden-scrollbar");
            }
        }
    }
```

here is function tabAccess

```
(function ($) {
$.fn.tabAccess = function () {
    return this.each(function () {
        $('a:hover, a:focus', 'input:hover', 'input.focus').css('outline', 'thin dashed grey');
        var $tabableElements = Array('A', 'INPUT');
        var $this = $(this);
        var keyName = { "tab": 9 };
        var flag = 0;
        var tabIndex = 1;
        beginIteration($this);

/*The idea behind this function is to traverse through all children of the 
dialog; as well as all their children, applying the tabindex attribute to
only the elements contained in $tabableElements defined above and skipping
the other elements*/

        function beginIteration(item) {
            item.children().each(function(index) {
                if ($.inArray($(this).attr('tagName'), $tabableElements) != -1) {
                    $(this).attr('tabindex', tabIndex);
                    tabIndex++;
                } else {
/*The code works when I put an alert in here
but it alerts every element that is not a match
for $tabableElements; so, clearly I can't keep this.

I have tried everything from setTimeout, to console.log,
but when I take this alert out, the code does not insert
tabindex into the elements I want.*/
                    alert($(this).attr('tagName');
                    beginIteration($(this));
                }
            });
        }

        $this.bind({
            keydown: function (e) {
                switch (e.keyCode) {
                    case keyName.tab:
                    {
                        e.preventDefault();

                        if (e.shiftKey) {
                            e.preventDefault();

                        }
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    });
};
})(jQuery);
```

Someone help!?

As always, thanks in advance... let me know if you need anymore information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so... the problem was something I hadn't mentioned in my question. For the record, if anyone should ever have this issue... it's probably already on here, but...

The problem was an ajax call into the dialog wasn't being given enough time to finish its execution.

Placing

```
var intervalHandler = setInterval(function() {
            if ($this.find('.loading').length == 0) {
                beginIteration($this);

                clearInterval(intervalHandler);
            }
        }, 500);
```

before the `beginIteration` call solved everything.

Comment: This also known as a race condition.